# php mail() not sending emails from different domains

Tags: php, email

I am using php's mail function to send emails. The problem is that, emails from different domains do not get sent. Only emails from my domain are sent. For example when i send an email from username@mydomain.com it is sent. When i send an email with from as username@yahoo.com or username@gmail .com the email is not sent.

When the emails get sent, they end up in the spam section.

Which headers do i need to bypass this restriction? Or any other solution.

thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the return value of the mail() function? If it returns true in both cases, then it may be an anti-spam filter issue. I had a similar issue before, and mails were sent correctly, but were blocked by our enterprise's anti-spam filter.

Comment: are you sure is not getting out? only because you dont receive it, it does not mean it does not get out.

Comment: They are going to the spam section. How did you solve your problem?

Comment: For the record, that's called phishing, unless you are using SMTP credentials, or have valid DKIM and SPF records.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on your SMTP server. This is likely to prevent spam from flowing out.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the fifth parameter in your mail() function:

```
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers,"-f ".$from);
```

NOTE: $from must be similar with the 'from' email address you've specified in the header.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the PEAR mail function http://pear.php.net/package/Mail .By using this you can send e-mail from a exchange server.But if you use sendmail server then you can use the below code.The below code will not work for microsoft exchange server

Hope it help u.

```
<?php
//new function
$to=//receipent email addressaddress;
$message=//Message;
$nameto = "Name of receipent";
$from = "abc@example.com";//sender address
$namefrom = "Test";//from name
$subject = "Subject of the mail";


function authSendEmail($from, $namefrom, $to, $nameto, $subject, $message)
{
    //SMTP + SERVER DETAILS
    /* * * * CONFIGURATION START * * * */
    $smtpServer = "mail.example.com";//mail server address
    $port = "25";//port
    $timeout = "30";
    $username = "test";//user name
    $password = "****";//password of sender
    $localhost = "1.2.3.4";//Ip address of mail server
    $newLine = "\r\n";
    /* * * * CONFIGURATION END * * * * */

    //Connect to the host on the specified port
    $smtpConnect = fsockopen($smtpServer, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout);
    $smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
        if(empty($smtpConnect))
        {
            $output = "Failed to connect: $smtpResponse";
            return $output;
        }
        else
        {
            $logArray['connection'] = "Connected: $smtpResponse";
        }

    //Request Auth Login
    fputs($smtpConnect,"AUTH LOGIN" . $newLine);
    $smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
    $logArray['authrequest'] = "$smtpResponse";

    //Send username
    fputs($smtpConnect, base64_encode($username) . $newLine);
    $smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
    $logArray['authusername'] = "$smtpResponse";

    //Send password
    fputs($smtpConnect, base64_encode($password) . $newLine);
    $smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
    $logArray['authpassword'] = "$smtpResponse";

    //Say Hello to SMTP
    fputs($smtpConnect, "HELO $localhost" . $newLine);
    $smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
    $logArray['heloresponse'] = "$smtpResponse";

    //Email From
    fputs($smtpConnect, "MAIL FROM: $from" . $newLine);
    $smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
    $logArray['mailfromresponse'] = "$smtpResponse";

    //Email To
    fputs($smtpConnect, "RCPT TO: $to" . $newLine);
    $smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
    $logArray['mailtoresponse'] = "$smtpResponse";

    //The Email
    fputs($smtpConnect, "DATA" . $newLine);
    $smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
    $logArray['data1response'] = "$smtpResponse";

    //Construct Headers
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $newLine;
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . $newLine;
    $headers .= "To: $nameto <$to>" . $newLine;
    $headers .= "From: $namefrom <$from>" . $newLine;

    fputs($smtpConnect, "To: $to\nFrom: $from\nSubject: $subject\n$headers\n\n$message\n.\n");
    $smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
    $logArray['data2response'] = "$smtpResponse";

    // Say Bye to SMTP
    fputs($smtpConnect,"QUIT" . $newLine);
    $smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);
    $logArray['quitresponse'] = "$smtpResponse";
}

if(authSendEmail($from, $namefrom, $to, $nameto, $subject, $message))
{echo "send";}
else{echo "failed";}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your [SMTP server is not allowing relay.](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html)  Talk to your mail server admin and ask if they will open relay for your application's IP address.